# uri file attribute in SDF files

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If the file path is relative, which is the base directory and how can we specify it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/182/uri-file-attribute-in-sdf-files/) by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) on 2012-11-09**:
I think its the directory of the world file, are you also getting directory not found error?

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2012-11-12**:
Hi,  I am getting an error that says "Image filename is empty"

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-11-14**:
I believe this is an error that you can ignore, and has been removed in the default branch. Are you experiencing any related problems?

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2012-11-16**:
when I specify a png heightmap, it doesn't load the heightmap, instead a large 2d black rectangle where the heightmap should be.  The Pioneer robot is next to this space on the ground.  I have attached a screenshot of gazebo, my heightmap mage, and the world file at http://inky.ws/g/2cz

**Comment by [logicalguy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24/logicalguy/) on 2012-11-16**:
oh, and I am using gazebo-1.2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Base paths for relative URIs are specified in environment variables. For example `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0